# Пагинация не отображается по URL .../page/17/

Tags: wordpress, ajax, pagination, ajax-load

Использую подгрузку постов через `AJAX`. Ещё работает поиск постов по категориям.

Заметил что когда перехожу на `URL` с видом пагинации `.../page/17/`, то страница выдаёт `404 Page Not Found`. Подскажите почему может не отображаться? Сайт закрыт от индексации и запароленный `basic AUTH`.
В настроках `Permalink` указано: `/%category%/%postname%/`

Цикл в файле `home.php`

```
$posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => [
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'terms' => 'all',
            'include_children' => false // Remove if you need posts from term 7 child terms
        ),
    ],
));

if (have_posts()) {
    $firstPost = get_posts()[0];
    set_query_var( 'firstPost', $firstPost );
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        get_template_part('blocks/page-blog/post-repeater');
    }
}
```

Метод подгрузки ajax с jQuery:

```
ajaxLoadMore: function (bottomOffset) {
    var thisClass = this,
        select = {
            action: 'loadmore',
            by_category: thisClass.categoryID,
            by_tags: thisClass.tagsArrayID,
            custom_post_type: $(thisClass.resultID).data('post-type'),
            query: pagination.param_posts,
            page: parseInt(pagination.current_page)
        };

    if (pagination.current_page >= pagination.max_pages) {
        return false;
    } // if there are no more pages

    if ($(document).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() - bottomOffset) && !$('body').hasClass('loading')) {

        console.log("Action: ajax Load More");

        $.ajax({
            url: options.ajax_url, // declarate in wordpress
            data: select,
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('body').addClass('loading');
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('body').removeClass('loading');
            },
            success: function (data) {

                $(thisClass.resultID).append(data); // paste html
                pagination.current_page++; // increase the number page

                // Search by tag
                thisClass.findByPostCategoryAndActivateButtonTags();
                addScrollByClickOnPostLinks();
                showCardPreview();
                addClampOfText(2,4);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/pagination-doesnt-work/

Comment: @KAGGDesign реализовано как в этой статье написано. Заметил если выводить посты через обекты, то работает правильно. В моем шаблоне используются функции the_title(), the_content().... Чтобы шаблон мог использовать эти функции добавил query_posts($posts); С ним не работает пагинация. Понял чтобы работала пагинация в моём случае необходимо было использовать созданный экземпляр класса ($posts) и выводить с него методы ($posts->have_posts()). Спасибо за статью, Вы мне всегда помогаете

Comment: Про query_posts надо забыть,  это функция для ядра.